# Question about uploaded files in ruby

Tags: ruby-on-rails, file-upload

When uploading a file I know I can access its properties but is it always the same or it varies? I mean, I am writing an app for myself where I can upload songs or videos to my server to watch later, and I'd like to populate the info about said files automatically as much as possible so I was wondering if it's possible to get things like length, quality, name, artists, artwork, or pick a first image like youtube does for its videos?

I'm fairly new to ruby (using rails) so I am unsure as to where to find this or if it's even possible

Answer (score 0):

You can do that using FFMpeg (read the license first).
FFMpeg gives you everything you were asking about and some more.
it's very powerful.

For mp3, check out [mp3-info](http://ruby-mp3info.rubyforge.org/), I haven't used it before but looks promising...